# Dapper insert into table that has a composite PK

Tags: c#, primary-key, dapper, dapper-extensions

I have a table that has a primary key composed of two columns, neither of which are auto-incrementing, and my Dapper insert (part of Dapper Extensions) is failing on the insert saying that the first of the two columns does not allow a null, even tho the value I'm passing in is not null.

Table `Student`:

```
StudentId (PK, not null)   \_ (combined to form primary key)
StudentName (PK, not null) /
Active                     -- just another column
```

C#:

```
public class Student {
  public int StudentId { get; set; }
  public string StudentName { get; set; }
  public bool Active { get; set; }
}

var newStudent = new Student { StudentId = 5, StudentName = "Joe", Active = true };
var insertSuccess = myConn.Insert<Student>(newStudent);
```

Error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StudentId', table 'dbo.Student'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Dapper is for some reason not getting the `StudentId` with a value of 5. Do I have to do something special for tables that have combined PK's, or with tables that have PK's that are *not* auto-incrementing? Thanks.

Comment: Does Dapper has an Insert extension method? [Performing Inserts and Updates with Dapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957774/performing-inserts-and-updates-with-dapper). Does the official `myConn.Execute("INSERT INTO Student (StudentId, StudentName, Active) VALUES (@StudentId, @StudentName, @Active)", new { StudentId = 5, StudentName = "Joe", Active = true});` works?

Comment: I'm using Dapper Extensions to do the insert, and that's what's throwing the error. I just tested your suggestion, and that does work. Was hoping to just use the extensions method because it's a lot less text to type out.

Comment: Can you post the _Insert_ extension method code? Is this one: https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/blob/master/DapperExtensions/DapperImplementor.cs?

Answer (score 11):

Adding an AutoClassMapper will change the behavior for all classes.  If you wish to handle just this one class you can create a Map for just this class.

```
public class StudentClassMapper : ClassMapper<Student>
{
    public StudentClassMapper()
    {
        Map(x => x.StudentId).Key(KeyType.Assigned);
        Map(x => x.StudentName).Key(KeyType.Assigned);
        AutoMap();  // <-- Maps the unmapped columns
    }
}
```

Comment: Added this to the docs https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/Customized-mapping-for-a-class

Answer (score 8):

Dapper.Contrib offers an annotation to solve this problem.

```
public class Student {
  [ExplicitKey]
  public int StudentId { get; set; }
  [ExplicitKey]
  public string StudentName { get; set; }
  public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

ExplicitKey means it is a key field whose value you must specify; it is not auto-generated by the database.

I'm assuming when you said "Dapper Extensions," you were referring to a different extension library. You may find you can easily switch over to Dapper.Contrib.

Comment: Although this works I must point out that `Get`, `GetAsync` `GetAll` and `GetAll` does not support composite keys.

Comment: Use one property as ExplicitKey. Then it will work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the problem, but AFAIK Dapper Extensions doesn't support composite primary keys by default.

You will probably have to code your own *AutoClassMapper*: https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/AutoClassMapper

The default AutoClassMapper makes certain assumptions about your database schema and POCOs:

- AutoClassMapper assumes that your table names are singular (Ex: Car table name and Car POCO name).
- Each POCO has at least one property named Id or ends with Id.
- If multiple properties end with Id, Dapper Extensions will use the first Id property as the primary key.
- If the Id property is determined to be an Integer, the KeyType will be set to Identity.
- If the Id property is determined to be a Guid, the KeyType will be set to Guid.
- If the id property is anything other than an Integer our Guid, the KeyType will be set to Assigned.