# Inserts using Dapper.NET

Tags: dapper

I am using Dapper.NET for my database connections.

So far, I have resorted to hand writing all the SQL I need for Inserts and Updates, I've found this old post from Sam Saffron

 [Performing Inserts and Updates with Dapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957774/performing-inserts-and-updates-with-dapper)

However, it doesn't lead to anything conclusive with regards to how to do inserts and updates from POCO objects, other than a few links to code that are several years old by now.

Since then, has a new small helper library to autogenerate what is needed popped up?

Comment: Take a look at the [Dapper.Contrib](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib)

Comment: Also [Dapper-Extensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions)

Comment: Thanks for the two suggestions, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Dapper.Contrib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper.Contrib/)

```
//Insert one entity
connection.Insert(new Car { Name = "Volvo" });

//Insert a list of entities
connection.Insert(cars);

//Update one entity
connection.Update(new Car() { Id = 1, Name = "Saab" });

//Update a list of entities
connection.Update(cars);
```

See more examples [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib).