# Dapper's parameterized Update and Insert?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I am using Dapper for my windows C# forms application. I noticed that most of their CRUD operations take class name as parameter.
For example two tables as below :

```
    "Employee" Table
        Column Name  | Data Type |
        -------------------------
        EmpName      | string    |
        EmpNo        | string    |
        --------------------------

Employee.cs
[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee
{
   [Key]
   public string EmpNo {get;set;}
   public string EmpName {get;set;}
}

    "User" Table
        Column Name   | Data Type |
        -------------------------
        UserName      | string    |
        UserNo        | string    |
        --------------------------
User.cs
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
   [Key]
   public string UserNo {get;set;}
   public string UserName {get;set;}
}


    eg. var users= connection.Query<User>("select * from User" );
        var employees = connnection.GetList<Employee>();
```

will do the appropriate tasks.
but, as per my knowledge `connection.Insert<User>(user); or connection.Update<Employee>(emp);` does not exist. 
Please correct me if I am wrong, is there any work around to have Update and Insert with letting dapper know the class type ? 
I am well aware about `Query()` and `Execute()`, in fact I am using those right now. Is there anyway possible to make it as easy as `GetList(ClassName);` is ?

Comment: You might want to look at the tag info http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dapper/info which has link to [Performing Inserts and Updates with Dapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957774/performing-inserts-and-updates-with-dapper)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Query and Execute functions, what I am looking for is to make Insert and Update as simple as GetList(ClassName) and Get(class) are.

Comment: @RahulMakwana You will need write your own wrapper to do that.  From what I understand, the people who wrote Dapper, did it as I answered below to leave things open ended. Often times, the code will need to only update specific columns, so passing an object would assume you want to update all columns, which is a big assumption for updates.  As it currently it, it is fairly precise code.

Comment: ?@BenHoffman I do understand that, what if I am fine with updating all the columns each time i make an update. I guess you are right, I need to write my own helper extension to do so.

Comment: Have you looked at dapper.contrib? It adds some CRUD features...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Marc Gravell. I found it [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/tree/master/Dapper.Contrib). 
Dapper's open source development do have  implementation for `Insert<ClassName>(obj)` and `Update<ClassName>(obj)`.

Answer (score 4):

Dapper handles things a bit differently than what you are asking for. There is no Insert or Update method. Instead you will want to do it like this for Insert:

```
var p = new Product { Name = "Sam", Description = "Developer" };
p.Id = cnn.Query<int>(@"insert Products(Name,Description) 
values (@Name,@Description) 
select cast(scope_identity() as int)", p).First();
```

This is directly from Sam Saffron, https://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/01/16/that-annoying-insert-problem-getting-data-into-the-db-using-dapper.

For Updates, you will want code like this:

```
public bool Update(Employee employee)
{
    string query = "UPDATE EMPLOYEE SET NAME = @Name WHERE Id = @Id";
    var count = this.db.Execute(query, employee);
    return count > 0;
}
```

Comment: Or just use `Execute` if you don't need to get the identity back out.

Comment: Note: dapper.contrib adds a lot of CRUD support